# How can we disable web security of chrome browser using selenium/TestNg

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use the following command using `selenium/testng` inside my code since every-time I execute the code, a new instance of browser is created by `webdriver` in which security is enabled by default.

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try something this, Change the path and slashing accoding to your specifications :-

```
            WebDriver driver=null;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src//lib//chromedriver");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("test-type");
            options.addArgument("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
            options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","./src//lib//chromedriver");
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
            driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Below is the link where all available chrome flags are listed :-

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I am still unable to open the url with Disable web security mode.. Is it possible to test desktop applications using selenium?

Comment: No it is not possible to test desktop application using selenium.

Comment: I have updated my answer. can you please try it again

Comment: i just passed options in ChromrDriver constr, now its working. thanks alot..          driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Comment: oops!! again one thing to say.. don't pass options instead of pass capabilities... capabilities itself contains options argument ... updated my answer again

Comment: `new ChromeDriver(capabilities)` is deprecated and the `new ChromeDriver(options)` are suggested to use