# How to disable dns over https in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing test using selenium, java, chrome.

How can I turn off "dns over https" in chrome settings?

I need it because my intranet DNS have different data than internet ones.

I've tried to add following options.

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); 
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.addArguments("--disable-async-dns");
    options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
    options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

It didn't help.
I've even tried to change options by clicking in settings

```
    driver.get("chrome://settings/security");
    String disableDNSOverHttpsButton = "/html/body/settings-ui//div[2]/settings-main//settings-basic-page//div[1]/settings-section[4]/settings-privacy-page//settings-animated-pages/settings-subpage/settings-security-page//settings-secure-dns//settings-toggle-button//div/cr-toggle";
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(disableDNSOverHttpsButton)));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(disableDNSOverHttpsButton)).click();
```

There is response "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: "

Comment: maybe this can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013378/how-can-we-disable-web-security-of-chrome-browser-using-selenium-testng

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi! Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local_state = {
    "dns_over_https.mode": "off",
    "dns_over_https.templates": "",
}

 

options.add_experimental_option("localState", local_state)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Finally I wrote it this way:



                `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); 

  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

  Map<String, Object> localState = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  localState.put("dns_over_https.mode", "off");

  localState.put("dns_over_https.templates", "");

  options.setExperimentalOption("localState", localState) ;

  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use setExperimentalOption.

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); 
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> localState = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    localState.put("dns_over_https.mode", "off");
    localState.put("dns_over_https.templates", "");
    options.setExperimentalOption("localState", localState) ;
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```