# How to disable dns over https in Undetected Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

i am using undetected chrome driver for my project.
i wanted to turn off Use Secure DNS option seen there `chrome://settings/security`.

i found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74334553 that using localState option we can achieve that and its working perfectly in simple selenium.

but in undetected chrome driver i get error "invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: localState", i guess thats because undetected chromedriver does not support experimental options.

so i did something like that:
attach user-data-dir in options.
make Local State file in that dir.
saved my json in that file.

Results:
when i launch driver and go to `chrome://settings/security` i see secure DNS option turned off, but it didnt make any effect in ja3 fingerprint.

sample code:

```
class ChromeWithPrefs(uc.Chrome):
def __init__(self, *args, options=None, **kwargs):
    if options:
        user_data_dir = os.path.normpath(tempfile.mkdtemp())
        options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={user_data_dir}")
        self._handle_local(options, user_data_dir)
        self._handle_prefs(options, user_data_dir)
    super().__init__(*args, options=options, **kwargs)

    # remove the user_data_dir when quitting
    self.keep_user_data_dir = False

@staticmethod
def _handle_prefs(options, user_data_dir):
    prefs = options.experimental_options.get("prefs")
    if prefs:
        # turn a (dotted key, value) into a proper nested dict
        def undot_key(key, value):
            if "." in key:
                key, rest = key.split(".", 1)
                value = undot_key(rest, value)
            return {key: value}

        # undot prefs dict keys
        undot_prefs = reduce(
            lambda d1, d2: {**d1, **d2},  # merge dicts
            (undot_key(key, value) for key, value in prefs.items()),
        )

        # create the preferences json file in its default directory
        default_dir = os.path.join(user_data_dir, "Default")
        os.mkdir(default_dir)

        prefs_file = os.path.join(default_dir, "Preferences")
        with open(prefs_file, encoding="latin1", mode="w") as f:
            json.dump(undot_prefs, f)

        # pylint: disable=protected-access
        # remove the experimental_options to avoid an error
        del options._experimental_options["prefs"]

@staticmethod
def _handle_local(options, user_data_dir):
    prefs = options.experimental_options.get("localState")
    if prefs:
        # turn a (dotted key, value) into a proper nested dict
        def undot_key(key, value):
            if "." in key:
                key, rest = key.split(".", 1)
                value = undot_key(rest, value)
            return {key: value}

        # undot prefs dict keys
        undot_prefs = reduce(
            lambda d1, d2: {**d1, **d2},  # merge dicts
            (undot_key(key, value) for key, value in prefs.items()),
        )

        # create the preferences json file in its default directory
        prefs_file = os.path.join(user_data_dir, "Local State")

        with open(prefs_file, encoding="latin1", mode="w") as f:
            json.dump(undot_prefs, f)

        # pylint: disable=protected-access
        # remove the experimental_options to avoid an error
        del options._experimental_options["localState"]

options_chrome = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  # undetected
options_chrome.add_argument("--start-maximized")
local_state = {
            "dns_over_https.mode": "off"
        }
 options_chrome.add_experimental_option('localState', local_state)

 driver = ChromeWithPrefs(
            options=options_chrome, suppress_welcome=True
        )
```